# How does the change in cavity length effect the interferometric frequency of a Fabry Perot cavity?

Tags: resonance, interferometry, fiber-optics

I'm working with FBG-based Fabry Perot interferometers, considering three FBGs in series to create 2 FP cavities. I'm confused about the following two things and cannot seem to get clear answers from anywhere:

1. How does one calculate the optical path length of a given FP cavity? Because the detuning factor (∂) is defined as the difference between the optical path lengths of the cavity one and two.
2. What is the relation between the obtained interferometric frequency of a cavity to its cavity length? So, I can understand when suppose the cavity is stretched how this frequency changes.

Any information would be appreciated.